# Angular: ViewModel for safe two-way binding & MVVM

Tags: typescript, mvvm, angular-2+

**Introduction**: Any angular dev should know that Angular tends to provide multiple ways of doing things.  When it comes to forms, I tend to prefer to rely on forms of the template-driven variety, and for dynamic template-driven forms, two-way binding with the default change detection strategy is helpful toward keeping your templates clean & simplified.  Unfortunately this often goes against the flow of some projects, more literally than figuratively especially when implementing uni-directional data flow with OnPush change detection.

**Goal**: The ViewModel class presented in this post is written with the intent of providing a safe, extensible context for mutable models which should easily support two-way binding, along with an integrated change detection mechanism for compatibility with varying overarching change detection strategies and data flow patterns.

**Addtional Thoughts**: A robust and flexible ViewModel definition may go a long way in implementing patterns closer to MVVM, with ViewModels acting as an intermediate layer between application state & views in cases where this may be desirable.

The ViewModel class:

```
export class ViewModel<TSpecialization extends ViewModel<TSpecialization, TModel>, TModel> {

    protected _model: {[key: string]: any} | undefined;
    protected _bound = false;
    private readonly _changed = new Subject<boolean>();

    get changed$(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this._changed.asObservable();
    }

    get asModel(): TSpecialization & TModel {
        if (this._bound) {
            return this as unknown as TSpecialization & TModel;
        } else {
            throw 'Model is unbound';
        }
    }

    private setProperty(value: any, key: string) {
        if (!isEquivalent((this._model as any)[key], value)) {
            (this.changed$ as Subject<boolean>).next(true);
        }
        this._model![key] = value;
    }

    protected static bind<TSpecialization extends ViewModel<TSpecialization, TModel>, TModel extends object>(specialization: TSpecialization, model: TModel) {
        specialization._model = model;
        for (var p of Object.entries(model)) {
            var key = p[0];
            Object.defineProperty(specialization, key, {
                get: () => specialization._model![key],
                set: (value) => specialization.setProperty(value, key)
            });
        }
        specialization._bound = true;
    }
}
```

An example showing how the VM might be integrated with dependency injection:

```
type MyData = {
  value: any
};

class MyVM extends ViewModel<MyVM, MyData> {
  
  constructor(dataSvc: DataService) {
    super();
    ViewModel.bind(this as MyVM, dataSvc.model);
  }
  
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grandparent',
  template: `
    <p>grandparent works!</p>
    <app-parent></app-parent>
    Outer value: {{vm.value}}

    <div>
        <button (click)="vm.value = vm.value + 1">Increment</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./grandparent.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MyVM,
      useFactory: (dataSvc: DataService) => new MyVM(dataSvc),
      deps: [ DataService ]
    }
  ]
})
export class GrandparentComponent implements OnDestroy {

  vm: MyVM & MyData;
  cleanup: Subscription[];

  constructor(chRef: ChangeDetectorRef, vm: MyVM) {
    chRef.detach();
    this.vm = vm.asModel;

    this.cleanup = [
      vm.changed$.subscribe(() => {
        chRef.detectChanges();
      })
    ];
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    for (var sub of this.cleanup) {
      sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

**Closing Thoughts**: This code is still in its infancy and is not battle-tested nor has it reached its final form.  It requires better support for more complex models and additional validation still needs to be performed on bind, but I thought I would get this out there early for any criticism, advice or feedback